# reading a buffer stream in tcl

Tags: tcl, file-handling

This is a question regarding file reading in tcl.
I am opening a buffer stream to write and i have only one file handler referece to it
Now while reading this buffer line by line, at some condition I have to put all the content of the buffer, Please suggest how can i achieve this.
So i am just pasting an example code to explain my requirement.

```
catch { open "| grep" r } pipe
while { [gets $pipe line] } {
      if { some_condition } {
          ## display all the content of $pipe as string
      }
}
```

Thanks
Ruchi

Answer (score 4):

To read from the pipe until it is closed by the other end, just use `read $pipe`. That then lets you do this:

```
set pipe [open "| grep" r]
while { [gets $pipe line] >= 0 } {  # zero is an empty line...
    if { some_condition } {
        puts [read $pipe]
        ### Or, to include the current line:
        # puts $line\n[read $pipe]
    }
}
```

If you want anything from earlier in the piped output, you must save it in a variable.

Comment: I also advise not putting a `catch` around the `open |...` like in the question, as the error messages you can get are never valid channel names.

Comment: Also it should be noted that GNU `grep` uses full buffering by default so if it's really intended to read its output linewise, it's advised to pass it the `--line-buffered` command line option. Not sure about other `grep` implementations.